# Need to count values of one row when another row has no value - SQL

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I want to get a count of the number of times column A has a value, but only to count it if column B has no value. This would need to be a SQL query to go into Data Studio and is being pulled from a Google Sheet.

Layout of what the Excel file looks like:
A1 - 2020-08-19
B1 -
*B1 is empty

Current formula (it's way off I know, but to give some context):

CASE(WHEN B = " ", THEN COUNT(A))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(case when B is null and A is not null then 1 else 0 end)`

or if count() doesn't count nulls (I'm not sure about bigquery) you could try:

`count(case when B is null then A end)`